# C++:How to have an array of boost::multi_array

Tags: c++, boost, multidimensional-array, boost-multi-array

Hi I have a few boost::multi_array defined as below:

```
typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> region_prior_integral_image
```

I am trying to create an array of `region_prior_integral_image` like the following:

```
unordered_map<string, int> filename_to_hash_key_map = get_filename_to_hash_key_map();

unordered_map<string, region_prior_integral_image> filename_to_region_prior_map = get_region_prior_integral_images();

region_prior_integral_image* image_cache = new region_prior_integral_image[5];
for(unordered_map<string, int>::iterator it = filename_to_hash_key_map.begin(); it != filename_to_hash_key_map.end(); it++){
    image_cache[it->second] = filename_to_region_prior_map[it->first];
}
```

However the program is terminating with the following: `SemanticTextonForest: /home/aly/libs/boost_1_51_0/stage/include/boost/multi_array/multi_array_ref.hpp:488: boost::multi_array_ref<T, NumDims>& boost::multi_array_ref<T, NumDims>::operator=(const ConstMultiArray&) [with ConstMultiArray = boost::multi_array<double, 3ul>, T = double, long unsigned int NumDims = 3ul, boost::multi_array_ref<T, NumDims> = boost::multi_array_ref<double, 3ul>]: Assertion`std::equal(other.shape(),other.shape()+this->num_dimensions(), this->shape())' failed.`

And I have no idea why?

I know I could just use a vector, but for arguments sake lets say I wanted to have an array of region_prior_integral_images

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have two `region_prior_integral_image` instances: A and B. If you want to assign B to A, like `A = B;`, the shapes of `A` and `B` must be equal. The error message is saying that, in your code `image_cache[it->second] = filename_to_region_prior_map[it->first];`, the two arrays are of different shapes.

How do you created the arrays in `filename_to_region_prior_map`? I guess you used this constructor to specify the shapes: `multi_array<double,3> B(boost::extents[i][j][k])`. Hence their shape is `[i][j][k]`. But when you create the `image_cache`, the default constructor is invoked. So the two shapes mismatch.

My opinion is to store pointers of `region_prior_integral_image` in your code, which will save a lot of copy as well.

Comment: any idea how to get the dimensions of an already created region_prior_image?

Comment: Use `const size_type*  shape() const;` like: `auto s = A.shape();`, then u can access it by `s[0]`, `s[1]` and `s[2]` in your case. Better read through the official reference: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html

Comment: How do I create the array of region_prior_images of a given size?

Comment: It is impossible. Only the default constructor will be invoked when using a primitive array. I suggest use `std::vector` instead, then u can use `std::vector::resize(n, region_prior_image(boost::extents[i][j][k]))` to fill it.